# Importing CSV files into Excel using a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, macros, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to develop a macro where in my Excel worksheet I type a date in a specific cell, and the macro will go into a folder containing text files. A database you could say. I want it to find the corresponding file name which is written as a date, put the data through a delimiter, and paste into the cells directly below where I originally put the date.

The folder will always be in the same place and the text files will all be formatted DD_MM_YYYY. And there cells below will always be empty

Some pictures to make what I'm asking easier to figure out.

[image: Result]
[image: Data Input Step 1]
[image: Data Input Step 2]
[image: Data Input Step 3]

Comment: Will the folder always be in the same place? Will the text files always have the same formatting? How much data will each file contain? What if the cells beneath your date entry already have data in them? Basically, what you're asking isn't very simple. :\

Comment: The Folder Will always be in the same place and the text files will all be formatted DD_MM_YYYY. And there cells below will always be empty. I'll do an edit to include a picture an example of the results I want. I'm sorry it's is a little complicated :( (although simple in concept imo but difficult to do)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is more simple than you may think, because you can invoke the Text Import Wizard (or rather, you can use its functionality) from within a macro, there's no need to write a CSV parser or anything fancy like that.

In fact, all I've done with the macro below is to use the built-in record function, and then tweak it a little bit to meet you needs.

#### Using the Macro:

1. Backup your current Excel file, in case something goes wrong.
2. Change the definition of `folder` in the macro to be the path containing all of your data files - make sure you include a trailing slash.
3. Select the header cell of the columns, which *must* contain the name of a one of your files - *including the file extension*. You can edit this field after the data is loaded if you wish to remove the extension.
4. Run the macro.

#### Actions

It will take the file name from the current cell, look in the specified `folder` and open that file specified in the cell. Then it will import it as CSV, exactly one cell *below* the selected cell (when starting the macro).

As such, it will probably overwrite the cells below the selected cell when running the macro - caution is advised.

If the file isn't found, or some other error occurs, this will fail with a normal VBA error box, no friendly error messages.

### Macro Code

Some of this can probably be trimmed - as said I get it from a recording rather than learning how to user `QueryTables` myself - but it won't hurt as it is, and seems to work reliably.

```
Sub LoadFromFile()
    Dim fileName As String, folder As String
    
    folder = "C:\Path\To\Your\Files\"
    fileName = ActiveCell.Value
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables _
        .Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & folder & fileName, Destination:=ActiveCell)
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Haha AMAZING! It works It works!! Thanks so Much Man :)!!

Comment: I figured out that if you add to the 5th line (fileName = ActiveCell.Value)  + ".txt" that you no longer have to enter it in the original cell. And it worked!

fileName = ActiveCell.Value + ".txt"